# Binomial expansion with negative power?

Tags: binomial-theorem

I tried searching everything but couldn't understand what formula or technique are they using to expand this term. I have attached image of my textbook for this problem. It's written there that we expand $(f(D))^{-1}$ in ascending power but I couldn't grasp it at all. Here is what they did: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6DZi.jpg

$$ \frac{1}{D^2+2D-5} = -\frac{1}{5}\left[1 - (2D/5 + D^2/5)\right]^{-1} = -\frac{1}{5} \left[ 1 + ( 2D/5 + D^2/5) + (2D/5 + D^2/5)^2 + \dotsb \right] $$

Can you please explain how to expand like this? What formula/technique do they use?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series maybe relevant

Comment: To clarify: are you interested in the expansion in general, or particularly the expansion in terms of a differential operator?

Comment: Geometric series assuming the D terms are small compared to 1

Comment: That is $$\frac {1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \; |x|<1$$

Comment: @Chappers I am interested the expansion in terms of a differential operator.